# brms project tests failed in jenkins build ( external drools files)

Tags: maven, jenkins, path, drools

i have a brms project that uses external drools files.

I want to build my project in jenkins, i also have many unit tests in the project.

the problem is that after buiding my project in jenkins all the tests failed!

i set the drools path in this file : **ejbModule/config.properties**

```
    rules.files.path = ..\\drools-files
```

in jenkins, i added the drools files as a module, so it's added to the same workspace where my project is build!

I guess the cause of the failed tests is that jenkins couldn't make the relation between the drools files and the path!

I looked in the net but nothing found about how to build brms project with external drools in jenkins!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! Jenkins doesn't use antislash () in path files, so i just replaced it by slash (/) :

```
          rules.files.path = ..//drools-files
```

and it's working !